# JMeter and CSRF

Tags: jmeter

I am doing performance testing of one of the application.
Below are the specifications of Application.
1. It is based on sharepoint 2013.It uses 
2. It uses JSON for interchanging data between the pages.
3. It uses NTLM authentication.
4. CSRF security fix is implemented in the application

Please fund below the problem description
 When I am running the recorded script, one of my page is showing "{ : "d":false| CSRF attack" "

Answer (score 0):

CSRF token it basically dynamic parameter, for Sharepoint it's usually called `__RequestVerificationToken`. You need to extract it from first page using one of the following PostProcessors:

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)

and use extracted value in second request. See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for comprehensive explanation and bypass example.

In order to deal with NTLM authentication use [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)

Comment: Thanks for ur rply. I am getting  response in JSON format so I am not able to see the token values in reponse received. Kindly assist for the same

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regular Expression Extractor, as Dmitri suggests.

The token must be there somewhere - CSRF works by sending a token as part of one request, then checking that the same token is received with the following request. Can you add an example of your JSON to your question?